# How do I set conditional formatting based on data in two different cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet and I want to set a fill color in one cell based on a date and a text value in two different cells. Essentially, A1 should be red if B1 date is older than 15 days ago AND C1 reads "These are words" I have tried multiple things but I cannot seem to find any formulas that work. I have listed below what formulas I have tried along with what effect they had. Any help would be appreciated.

Additionally, I apologize if this has been answered somewhere, I looked but could not find anything.

Only highlights date that is EXACTLY 15 days ago
`=AND($B:$B=TODAY()-15,$C:$C="These Are Words")`

Does not Highlight anything
`=AND(=ISBETWEEN($B:$B=TODAY()-15,=TODAY(),$C:$C="These Are Word")`

I have also tried setting specific cells (i.e. B1 instead of $B:$B)

[Example of desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHkJ4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Instead of the `=` operator use the `<=` operator:

`=AND($B:$B<=(TODAY()-15),$C:$C="These Are Words")`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still new to figuring these out and hadn't thought of using the <= operator